# Как объединить два существующих сайта в один мультисайт?

Tags: wordpress

На wordpress есть режим мультисайта, когда можно создавать целую сеть нескольких свои сайтов.
Это хорошо создавать с нуля, когда устанавливается чистая копия вордпресс и на ней строится уже контент.
А что делать когда собираешься объединить в сеть два уже сконфигурированных сайта?
На основном домене у меня получилось активировать сеть, точнее выбрать его за основу создания сети. Но вот добавить второй сайт не выходит полноценно. То медиафайлов нету вообще, не говоря о том что в записях ссылки будут иным на фото, в базе сайта из консоли.
То настройки темы сбиты вообще, хорошо хоть записи и комменты есть еще.

Comment: Как вариант не объединять в сеть, а использовать управление одного из другого https://wordpress.org/plugins/mainwp/

Comment: @SeVlad но почему? вроде как использование мультисайта как минимум позволяет экономить место на хостинге. вместо тысячи повторных копий вордпресс стоит одна , как и БД (правда вот БД лучше разделять бы считаю)

Comment: БД одна, но почти все таблицы продублированы по количеству сайтов сети.

Comment: @BiLBerry я просто альтернативное решение предложил. Скрещивание - то процесс такой, рискованный. А потом может и разделять придётся...

Comment: @KAGGDesign да? не знал. тогда с чего будет экономия объема если (почти) все дублируется все равно.... странно

Comment: @SeVlad да, по этому поводу уверенности тоже нет. считаю раздельно создавать лучше. пока вижу логичность мультисайта при создании локализованного сайта когда есть смысл разделить а не ставить плагин типа polylang к примеру. многие блогеры пишут мол объединять лучше создавая для бизнеса разные по типу сайты, блоги, лендинг страницы. но в таком варианте считаю наоборот. логичнее разделять и проще сократить после численность сайтов или что то массово скорректировать в них

Comment: но спасибо за ответы, скорее оставлю отдельно сайты чем их объединять.

Comment: Про экономию объёма вы сказали )) На самом деле по базе - экономии нет. По файлам - есть. Но смысл мультисайта не в этом, а в возможности использовать одинаковый набор плагинов и одной темы для нескольких сайтов сети, что упрощает обслуживание сети в целом.

Comment: то есть, если планируется создание сайтов в каждом из которых будут разные темы, а не одинаковые, то и выгоды нет с этого, так? блогеры часто и на БД ссылаются в экономии при этом указывая если сайтов будет много и много статей то БД будет огромной конечно. а по каким именно файлам экономия? это важно

Comment: Темы конечно могут быть активированы разные. А *набор* доступных плагинов, как и *набор* тем - один на всех. wp.com - это и есть мультисайт. Экономия.. разве что на объём дистрибутива (сейчас около 8мб на каждый **доп** сайт). Это совсем не то место, где стоит экономить.

Comment: По поводу мультиязычности - как правило лучше плагин, чем иные решения.

Comment: зато меньше места занимают под каждый одинаковый набор тем и плагинов обновления для них же